# Registering an app for receiving all file types in SEND action

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-contentprovider, intentfilter

What I want is a custom `intent-filter`  that can receive **any file types** like text, audio, image, video, apk, pdf, word, excel, power point, **etc** sharing from other apps. The important thing that must be mentioned is that my app is a file sharing app. Using  mentioned `mimeType` in `intent-filter`, caused any sharing content received in my app like shared location, text and everything else. However I want to accept only **physical shared files**:

`<data android:mimeType="*/*"/>`

And also based on this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#DataTest) which said:

> filters can list just a data type and don't need to explicitly name
>   the `content`: and `file`: schemes

putting these two schemes (`file` and `content`) with mentioned `mimetype` doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: What is a physical shared file?

Comment: @greenapps excuse me for using ambiguous word. I mean those files which exactly are on the internal or external memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Using mentioned mimeType, caused any sharing content received in my app like shared location, text and everything else.

Well, sure. `ACTION_SEND` is for sharing content.

> However I want to accept only physical shared files

That is not possible on Android using `ACTION_SEND`. You are welcome to use some other `Intent` action, such as `ACTION_VIEW`, where the scheme used in your `<intent-filter>` will be applied.

Comment: Thanks to your attention. But SEND action is appropriate option for me. With these mimeTypes I can receive all the file types I mentioned in my question except text file.  application/*, image/* video/* but when I add text/* mimeType I receive all the shared content like location! My question is how I can exclude these extra content (location and copied text etc)

Comment: @NavaIghani: "My question is how I can exclude these extra content (location and copied text etc)" -- you can't. `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` will contain whatever the sending app wants, and you have no control over what they are. Sorry!